# REGEX to remove line if it doesn't begin with X

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to parse information regarding users last modified directories using perl.

However, I'm only interested in users beginning with "U" or "u" Is it possible with a REGEX to remove every line that doesn't start with a "u" or "U"?

> $VAR1 = 'rachel     512 2014-09-22 10:45:40.584528000 +0100
>
> $VAR1 = 'bob        512 2012-08-15 11:32:17.000773000 +0100
>
> $VAR1 = 'connel     512 2014-07-23 17:43:54.988200000 +0100
>
> $VAR1 = 'jim        512 2014-09-25 14:54:21.080627000 +0100
>
> $VAR1 = 'jackson    512 2014-08-21 11:14:35.686864000 +0100
>
> $VAR1 = 'mel        512 2014-08-19 12:01:30.773249000 +0100
>
> $VAR1 = 'sam        512 2014-09-25 15:44:06.764874000 +0100
>
> $VAR1 = 'u08805     512 2014-01-04 12:16:47.358653000 +0000
>
> $VAR1 = 'u08828     512 2014-09-23 08:30:11.000794000 +0100
>
> $VAR1 = 'u21491     512 2014-07-09 16:04:48.101059000 +0100
>
> $VAR1 = 'u23303     512 2014-09-25 14:33:05.044120000 +0100
>
> $VAR1 = 'u23841     512 2014-08-15 03:15:29.317542000 +0100
>
> $VAR1 = 'u23920     512 2014-07-23 09:42:35.211670000 +0100

This is what I have currently, I've already have to split and use REGEX to get to this stage.

```
my %timestamp;
$count = 0;

$stdout = $ssh->capture("ls -ladE /export/home/*");
@lines = split(/\n/,$stdout);

foreach(@lines)
   {
    my @firstsplit = split(/drwxr-x---/,$_);
    $firstsplit[1] =~s/^\s+|\s+$//g; #removes whitespace
    $firstsplit[1] =~ s/^\S+\s*//; #removes first number from string
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter out every string of an array except those that start with `u` or `U`, use

```
@a = grep { /^[uU]/ } @a;
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not quite clear what you are asking, but this simple program demonstrates how to extract only lines starting with `u` or `U`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
while(<>) {
    if (/^[uU]/) { print; }
    # alternate line: print if /^u/i;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ ./extract.pl < textfile
u08805 512 2014-01-04 12:16:47.358653000 +0000
u08828 512 2014-09-23 08:30:11.000794000 +0100
...
```

You might like to extend your pattern to include leading whitespace:

```
while(<>) {
    if (/^\s*(u.*)/i) { print $1, "\n"; }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the `i` flag to do a case insensitive search. `if(/^u/i){print;}`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work as well.

```
 #  s/(?mi)(?:^(?!u).*\r?\n)+//g

 (?mi)
 (?:
      ^ 
      (?! u )
      .* \n 
 )+
```

Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;

my $logdata = <DATA>;

$logdata =~ s/(?i)(?:^(?!u).*\n)+//mg;

print $logdata;

__DATA__

rachel 512 2014-09-22 10:45:40.584528000 +0100
bob 512 2012-08-15 11:32:17.000773000 +0100
connel 512 2014-07-23 17:43:54.988200000 +0100
jim 512 2014-09-25 14:54:21.080627000 +0100

jackson 512 2014-08-21 11:14:35.686864000 +0100
mel 512 2014-08-19 12:01:30.773249000 +0100 

sam 512 2014-09-25 15:44:06.764874000 +0100 
u08805 512 2014-01-04 12:16:47.358653000 +0000 
u08828 512 2014-09-23 08:30:11.000794000 +0100 
U21491 512 2014-07-09 16:04:48.101059000 +0100 
u23303 512 2014-09-25 14:33:05.044120000 +0100
jim 512 2014-09-25 14:54:21.080627000 +0100
u23841 512 2014-08-15 03:15:29.317542000 +0100 
u23920 512 2014-07-23 09:42:35.211670000 +0100
```

Answer (score 1):

Better you can try this will help you a lot....

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = qq('uachel 512 2014-09-22 10:45:40.584528000 +0100

'bob 512 2012-08-15 11:32:17.000773000 +0100

'connel 512 2014-07-23 17:43:54.988200000 +0100

'jim 512 2014-09-25 14:54:21.080627000 +0100

'jackson 512 2014-08-21 11:14:35.686864000 +0100

'mel 512 2014-08-19 12:01:30.773249000 +0100

'sam 512 2014-09-25 15:44:06.764874000 +0100

'u08805 512 2014-01-04 12:16:47.358653000 +0000

'u08828 512 2014-09-23 08:30:11.000794000 +0100

'u21491 512 2014-07-09 16:04:48.101059000 +0100

'u23303 512 2014-09-25 14:33:05.044120000 +0100

'u23841 512 2014-08-15 03:15:29.317542000 +0100

'u23920 512 2014-07-23 09:42:35.211670000 +0100);

 $string =~ s{^((?:(?!'u).)+)}{}isgm;
 print $string;exit;
```